# LINQ orderby from specific value

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

Sample:

```
var aux = new int[] { -1,0,1,-1,2,3,4,5,6,7 }
```

Expected result:

```
{ 2,3,4,5,6,7,1,0,-1,-1 }
```

How?

--

Edit: Sorry for the poor question. 
I want to order all from the value 2, and others who are put in the lower end (I fixed the text).

Comment: You'll have to explain what you're trying to get.

Comment: Is this a random order and a trick question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = aux
  .OrderBy(i => i < 2 ? 2 : 1) //small numbers last
  .ThenBy(i => i < 2 ? -i : i); //large numbers asc, small numbers desc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var res = aux.Where(a => a>=2 ).OrderBy (a => a)
             .Concat(aux.Where (a => a <2).OrderByDescending (a => a))
```